# Chamar nova Activity através de um ImageView

Tags: android

Eu preciso chamar uma nova `Activity` através do *click* em uma `ImageView`.

Segue meu código:

```
final ImageView botaoAbrirMesas = (ImageView) findViewById(R.botoes_laucher.openMesas);

    botaoAbrirMesas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent();
            it.setClass(null, PrincipalActivity.class);

            startActivity(it);
        }
    });
```

Porém ao executar a aplicação encerra-se devido a um erro. Este é o modo certo de usar ou não posso usar o *click* em uma `ImageView`?

Answer (score 2):

Julgo que o problema está em você passar `null` no método `setClass`.

Substitua o seu código por este:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, PrincipalActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Substitua `Main.this` por `NomeDaSuaActividade.this`

Caso você queira utilizar o método `setClass` substitua `null` por `NomeDaSuaActividade.this`

Comment: Além de fazer o que o @ramaral postou, não esqueça de declarar a nova Activity no `AndroidManifest.xml` 
<activity android:name="com.package.app. NomeDaSuaActividade"
android:label="NomeDaSuaActividade" >
</activity>

Comment: Obrigada por lembrar isso. Mas a actividade a declarar é `PrincipalActivity` e não `NomeDaSuaActividade`. Pelo menos no contexto em que `NomeDaSuaActividade`é utilizado no meu exemplo.