# Erro ao tentar acessar outra tela usando um Botao

Tags: java

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu tenho a minha tela principal que contem um botão para acessar outra tela, o código na qual estou usando para fazer essa ligação é:

```
btRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    }
});
```

Acontece que dentro desta nova tela(*activity_register*) eu tenho vários campos(EditText) e dois botões, *Registrar* e *Limpar*, a tarefa do botão *Registrar* é que quando for pressionado ele colete os valores dos campos(EditText) e insira na *String*, para isso estou usando o seguinte codigo:

Parte 1:

```
EditText etRegisterName,etRegisterSecondName,etRegisterAge,etRegisterEmail,etRegisterPhone;
```

Parte 2:

```
name = etRegisterName.getText().toString();
secondname = etRegisterSecondName.getText().toString();
age = etRegisterAge.getText().toString();
email = etRegisterEmail.getText().toString();
phone = etRegisterPhone.getText().toString();
```

Resumindo, minha *MainActivy* esta assim:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText etSearch;
    EditText etRegisterName,etRegisterSecondName,etRegisterAge,etRegisterEmail,etRegisterPhone;
    Button btSearch,btRegister,btRegisterFinish;

    String name, secondname, age, email, phone;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Search);
        btSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Search_Button);
        btRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Register_Button);
        btRegisterFinish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btRegisterFinish);

        etRegisterName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegisterName);
        etRegisterSecondName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegisterSecondName);
        etRegisterAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegisterAge);
        etRegisterEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegisterEmail);
        etRegisterPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRegisterPhone);

        btSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                String busca = etSearch.getText().toString();

                String tableTest = name+secondname+age+email+phone;

                String[][] table = {{"Rosana","De Oliveira","39","foo@bar.com","(00) 5555-5555"},
                                    {"Jackson","De Almeida","15","baz@poo.com","(00) 6666-66666"}};

                for(int i=0;i < table.length;i++){
                    for(int j=0;j < table[i].length;j++){

                        if(busca.contains(table[i][j]) == true){                            
                            AlertDialog.Builder searchOK = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                            searchOK.setTitle("Busca Concluida");
                            searchOK.setMessage("Nome: " + table[i][0] + "\n" 
                                                + "Sobrenome: " + table[i][1] + "\n" 
                                                + "Idade: "  + table[i][2] + "\n" 
                                                + "E-mail: " + table[i][3] + "\n" 
                                                + "Telefone: " + table[i][4]);

                            searchOK.setNeutralButton("Fechar", null);
                            searchOK.show();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        btRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
            }
        });
        btRegisterFinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                name = etRegisterName.getText().toString();
                secondname = etRegisterSecondName.getText().toString();
                age = etRegisterAge.getText().toString();
                email = etRegisterEmail.getText().toString();
                phone = etRegisterPhone.getText().toString();

                AlertDialog.Builder confirmRegister = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                confirmRegister.setTitle("Dados do Registro:");
                confirmRegister.setMessage("Nome: " + name + "\n"
                                            + "Sobrenome: " + secondname + "\n"
                                            + "Idade: " + age + "\n"
                                            + "E-mail: " + email + "\n"
                                            + "Telefone: " + phone);
                confirmRegister.setNeutralButton("Alterar", null);
                confirmRegister.setPositiveButton("Registrar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {                  
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                        AlertDialog.Builder alertSucess = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        alertSucess.setTitle("Registrado!");
                        alertSucess.setMessage("Registro feito com Sucesso!");
                        alertSucess.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
                    }
                });
                confirmRegister.show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Meu problema é que quando tento acessar essa tela(*activity_register*) da erro dizendo que a aplicação parou! Eu nem sequer consigo acessar a outra tela onde esta o botão para completar o Registro, alguém tem ideia do que pode ser? se a pergunta ficou confusa me desculpe, deixe nos comentários que tentarei explicar melhor!

Comment: Jeiferson, não é recomendado chamar o `setContentView` mais de uma vez para uma determinada `Activity`, apesar de funcionar, pode ser complicado gerenciar as referências fazendo essa troca. Por que não inicia outra `Activity` ou até mesmo utilizar `Fragment` para apresentar uma nova tela? Essa pergunta pode esclarecer alguns detalhes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22227950/android-is-using-setcontentview-multiple-times-bad-while-changing-layouts.

Comment: Vou tentar, mas é que não começo outra forma de chamar tela a não ser usando o setContent...

Comment: Você pode iniciar uma nova `Activity` usando um `Intent`. Acho que essas perguntas podem te ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11455/chamar-nova-activity-atraves-de-uma-imagemview, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42346/como-abrir-uma-activity-j%C3%A1-aberta-antes e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17483/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-desenhar-na-activity-e-no-fragment

Comment: A um tempo, passei por uma situação bem semelhante. Sugiro dar uma lida nessa pergunta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17633/

Comment: @emanuelsn, eu fiz um teste, retirei o código do botão "Registrar que esta localizado na activity_register e funcionou normalmente, chamou a tela, ai eu andei pensando, cada tela tem que ter sua classe .java para administrar ela?

Comment: Exato. Cada activity (tela) deve ter sua classe para que você identifique os componentes da tela, as ações de click/touch e etc.  Lembre-se, que cada activity deve estar declarada no Android Manifest, se não, irá causar uma falha na .apk.

Comment: Sim, eu estava colocando o código das acoes da outra activity na activity_main, por isso não funcionava, vlw!